# Python web scraper printing the value '0.00'

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm new here and need your help for my master's thesis. I need to save data from a charger web interface to an Excel file. So far I can call up the web interface and can also save the data in an Excel list. But I always get a "0.00" as the return value for voltage and current, although the values are constantly changing.

Here is my code what I wrote. And a screenshot of the web interface.

I thank you in advance for your support

```
import csv
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import datetime

# Hier den Wert end = '13.7' eintragen! für Spannung
end = '13.67'

def holedaten():
    url = ('http://mcb:8080/')
    r = requests.get(url, auth=('admin', 'mcb'))
    web_content = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    #time.sleep(1)
    zeitaktuell = datetime.datetime.now()
    datum = zeitaktuell.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    uhrzeit = zeitaktuell.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    # Udev - Spannung vom Ladegerät
    Udev = web_content.find(id='voltageset').text
    # Ubatt - Spannung Batterie
    Ubatt = web_content.find(id='voltage').text
    # Ibatt - Strom Batterie
    Ibatt = web_content.find(id='current').text
    # Ahges - Ah-Zähler
    Ahges = web_content.find(id='MCBAmpere').text
    # mcbdauer - Aktuelle Dauer
    mcbdauer = web_content.find(id='MCBRunTime').text

    meineliste = [datum, uhrzeit, Udev, Ubatt, Ibatt, Ahges, mcbdauer]
    #print(meineliste)
    #print(Ahges)
    #print(mcbdauer)
    return meineliste



with open('real_data.csv', 'w', newline='')as csvfile:
    condition = True

    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    tst = ['Datum', 'Uhrzeit', 'Udev', 'Ubatt', 'Ibatt', 'Ahges', 'mcbdauer', 'Identdauer', 'Batterie']
    writer.writerow(tst)

    while condition == True:
        daten = holedaten()
        # daten(2) wäre Udev; 0=datum 1=Uhrzeit 2=Udev 3=Ubatt...
        bis = daten[3]
        writer.writerow(daten)
        print(daten)
        #if bis <= end:
           # condition = False
            #print("Wert erreicht!")
```

My results:

```
['14-10-2021', '10:59:01', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '', '']
['14-10-2021', '10:59:05', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '', '']
['14-10-2021', '10:59:08', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '', '']
['14-10-2021', '10:59:11', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '', '']
['14-10-2021', '10:59:14', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '', '']
['14-10-2021', '10:59:17', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '', '']
```

Here is the Screenshot.

[voltage and current values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEkyi.jpg)
[Amperehours and Runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ERrq.jpg)

Comment: your thesis is not relevant, keep your question neutral please

Comment: probably loaded dynamically. Check your Network -> XHR to see if the data is pulled in from an api. Or check the source html to see if it's stored in a script tag in json format. Right click and View source. There you can see what you're actually pulling in as the html on the request

Comment: thx @chitown88. I think it´s a script in .js format. So what can I do? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the direct request for that data. Try:

```
import csv
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import datetime

# Hier den Wert end = '13.7' eintragen! für Spannung
end = '13.67'

def holedaten():
    url = ('http//mcb:8080/MCBStatus.xml')
    xml_response = requests.get(url, auth=('admin', 'mcb'))
    xml = xml_response.text
    xml_content = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml')
   
    clock = xml_content.find('clock').text
   
    datum = clock.split()[0]  # <--
    uhrzeit = clock.split()[-1]  # <--
    # Udev - Spannung vom Ladegerät
    Udev = xml_content.find('voltageset').text  # <--
    # Ubatt - Spannung Batterie
    Ubatt = xml_content.find('voltage').text  # <--
    # Ibatt - Strom Batterie
    Ibatt = xml_content.find('current').text  # <--
    # Ahges - Ah-Zähler
    Ahges = xml_content.find('mcbampere').text
    # mcbdauer - Aktuelle Dauer
    mcbdauer = xml_content.find('mcbruntime').text

    meineliste = [datum, uhrzeit, Udev, Ubatt, Ibatt, Ahges, mcbdauer]
    #print(meineliste)
    #print(Ahges)
    #print(mcbdauer)
    return meineliste



with open('real_data.csv', 'w', newline='')as csvfile:
    condition = True

    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    tst = ['Datum', 'Uhrzeit', 'Udev', 'Ubatt', 'Ibatt', 'Ahges', 'mcbdauer', 'Identdauer', 'Batterie']
    writer.writerow(tst)

    while condition == True:
        daten = holedaten()
        # daten(2) wäre Udev; 0=datum 1=Uhrzeit 2=Udev 3=Ubatt...
        bis = daten[3]
        writer.writerow(daten)
        print(daten)
        #if bis <= end:
           # condition = False
            #print("Wert erreicht!")

    #f1 = open("inFile", "r")  # open input file for reading


print('finished')
```